# How to append HTML form data to a JSON object using HTML5 local storage feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

We are building a web application using HTML5, JS. We want to store HTML form data in a JSON format in offline without submitting the form. Once connected to internet we want to submit the form. We may have multiple form records so all the form data should be appended to the JSON file. So is it possible to achieve this with the new HTML5 'Local Storage' and JSON using native JS/jquery? Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
    <form action="#" name="StudentRegistration" onsubmit="dataSave()" onchange="dataSave()">
   <table cellpadding="5" width="400" bgcolor="f2f2f2" align="center"
      cellspacing="5" border="0" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;">
      <tr>
         <td colspan=2>
            <center><font size=4><b>Student Registration Form</b></font></center>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td width="40%">Name</td>
         <td width="60%"><input type="text" class="field" name=textnames id="textname" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Father Name</td>
         <td><input type="text" class="field" name="fathername" id="fathername"
            size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Postal Address</td>
         <td><input type="text" class="field" name="paddress" id="paddress" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Personal Address</td>
         <td><input type="text" class="field" name="personaladdress"
            id="personaladdress" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Sex</td>
         <td><input type="radio" class="field" name="sex" value="male" size="10">Male
            <input type="radio" class="field" name="sex" value="Female" size="10">Female
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>City</td>
         <td>
            <select name="City" class="field" id="city">
               <option value="-1" selected>select..</option>
               <option value="New Delhi">NEW DELHI</option>
               <option value="Mumbai">MUMBAI</option>
               <option value="Goa">GOA</option>
               <option value="Patna">PATNA</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Course</td>
         <td>
            <select name="Course" class="field" id="course">
               <option value="-1" selected>select..</option>
               <option value="B.Tech">B.TECH</option>
               <option value="MCA">MCA</option>
               <option value="MBA">MBA</option>
               <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>District</td>
         <td>
            <select name="District" class="field" id="district">
               <option value="-1" selected>select..</option>
               <option value="Nalanda">NALANDA</option>
               <option value="UP">UP</option>
               <option value="Goa">GOA</option>
               <option value="Patna">PATNA</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>State</td>
         <td>
            <select Name="State" class="field" id="state">
               <option value="-1" selected>select..</option>
               <option value="New Delhi">NEW DELHI</option>
               <option value="Mumbai">MUMBAI</option>
               <option value="Goa">GOA</option>
               <option value="Bihar">BIHAR</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>PinCode</td>
         <td><input type="text" class="field" name="pincode" id="pincode" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>EmailId</td>
         <td><input type="text" class="field" name="emailid" id="emailid" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>DOB</td>
         <td><input type="text" class="field" name="dob" id="dob" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>MobileNo</td>
         <td><input type="text" class="field" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="reset" class="btns"></td>
         <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" class="btns" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var setFieldString = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fieldString')); 
    //var radio = localStorage.getItem('radioValue');
    console.log(setFieldString);
    $("#textname").val(setFieldString.textname);
    $("#fathername").val(setFieldString.fathername);
    $("#paddress").val(setFieldString.paddress);
    $("#personaladdress").val(setFieldString.personaladdress);
    $("#city").val(setFieldString.city);
    $("#course").val(setFieldString.course);
    $("#district").val(setFieldString.district);
    $("#state").val(setFieldString.state);
    $("#pincode").val(setFieldString.pincode);
    $("#emailid").val(setFieldString.emailid);
    $("#dob").val(setFieldString.dob);
    $("#mobileno").val(setFieldString.mobileno); 
});
function dataSave(){
    var fields = {};
    $('.field').each(function(){
        fields[this.id] = this.value;
    }) 
    localStorage.setItem('fieldString',JSON.stringify(fields));

          // Output: {"field-01":"on","field-02":"1234"}
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fieldString')));   //Output: Object {field-01: "on", field-02: "1234"}
}
```

Comment: Yes, but bear in mind localStorage/JSON are string-based; so if your form allows complex types such as file uploads, they will be lost when you serialise the form data.

Comment: What you are describing is a *"progressive web app"* ( PWA). Do some research on that. Google has a good primer https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just collect all the form data into an object and push that object to an array, so you can have the data of multiple forms inside the array.
Then stringify that array and write it to local.
Keep in mind the localStorage limits if you're storing huge amounts of strings.

The `navigator.onLine` property returns true or false to state the current online/offline status of the browser.

And you can listen for the `online` and `offline` event in the browsers that support it to restore the state and submit the form.

`window.addEventListener( 'online', event => { ... });`